# Rounding to the second decimal place in python

Tags: python, formatting

I am writing a script for school that consists of converting either miles to kilometers or vis versa. However, I can't seem to find the proper way to convert the output to only go to the second decimal place. How would I write this code better to format the output of milesToKilometers and kilometersToMiles to only go to the second decimal place? I have tried a few variations but I can't seem to get it correct.

```
def main():
    # Declare local variables
    miles = 0
    kilometers = 0
    convert = ""

    # Get user input
    convert = str(input("Would you like to convert miles to kilometers or kilometers to miles?"))

    # If / Else Statement
    if convert == "miles to kilometers":
        miles = int(input("How many miles do you want to convert to kilometers?"))
        milesOutput = milesToKilometers(miles)
        print(miles ,"miles converted to kilometers is", milesOutput)
    elif convert == "kilometers to miles":
        kilometers = int(input("How many kilometers do you want to convert to miles?"))
        kilometerOutput = kilometersToMiles
        print(kilometers, "kilometers convert to miles is", kilometerOutput)
    else:
        print("Invalid Input. Restart to try again.")

def milesToKilometers(miles):
    mileConverstion = miles * 1.60934
    return mileConverstion

def kilometersToMiles(kilometers):
    kilometerConverstion = kilometers * 0.621371
    return kilometerConverstion

# Start Program
main()
```

Comment: you can use `round(some_number, 2)`

Comment: @rcshon this is not what OP wants, and is almost never the solution in general. Floating-point numbers don't *have* decimal digits, so mathematically trying to approximate a decimal number doesn't always give something that will print nicely. Please see https://0.30000000000000004.com/ and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the built-in `round` function to round a number to up to 2 decimal places. Seems like you only need to include this in the `milesToKilometers` and `kilometers to miles` functions.

```
def milesToKilometers(miles):
    mileConverstion = miles * 1.60934
    return round(mileConverstion, 2)

def kilometersToMiles(kilometers):
    kilometerConverstion = kilometers * 0.621371
    return round(kilometerConverstion, 2)
```

Note: If you want the output to keep the trailing zeros e.g. `2.10`, you need to convert it into a string as numerical values omit trailing zeros. You can convert to a string like this:

`with_decimals = f'{round(number, 2):.2f}'`

Answer (score 0):

You can also do the formatting by using format strings as follows

```py
miles = 3.1415
print(f'{miles:.1f}') # 1 decimal places
print(f'{miles:.2f}') # 2 decimal places
# and so on
```

Keep in mind that this is rounding and not truncating which may or may not be what you want.

Comment: Another thing to note is this will pad your output with 0's to the exact number of decimal places specified